# How to stop a Gutenberg Block from firing multiple GET Requests?

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, javascript, rest-api

I've been building a Gutenberg Block that sends a `GET` request to the Woocommerce REST API.

It is composed of a text `input` that receives an ID of a product and fetches it to the Woocommerce REST API. It also has a `button` that fires a function to fetch the product  with the API.

#### The issue with the GET Requests

The fetching works well, but it keeps sending multiple `GET` requests, even when I do not click the button to fire the function. Simply clicking the input sends multiple requests when I only need one everytime I change the ID and click the button.

I'm importing `WooCommerceRestApi` from `"@woocommerce/woocommerce-rest-api"` and use Node.js.

#### The code

This is the first part of the edit function:

```js
const edit = ({ attributes, setAttributes }) => {

    const blockProps = useBlockProps();

    // Wrapped the WooCommerce.get() function in a function named `fetchingId` to call it with a button
    const fetchingId = async (id) => {
      // The WooCoommerce.get() function
      const response = await WooCommerce.get(`products/${id}`)
        .then((response) => {
          console.log(response.data);
          setAttributes({ price: response.data.price });
          setAttributes({ name: response.data.name });
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log(error.response.data);
          setAttributes({ price: '' });
          setAttributes({ name: '' });
        });
    }

    ...

  }
```

This is another part of the function: an input that updates the `Product ID` that is used for the `GET` request and a button linked to the `fetchingId()` function.

```
return <div {...blockProps}>
    <div class="wrapper-input" >
        <TextControl
          label={__('ID du Produit', 'ingredient-unique')}
          value={attributes.id}
          onChange={(val) => setAttributes({ id: val })}
          className='control-id'
        />
    </div>
    <button onclick={fetchingId(attributes.id)}>Chercher le produit</button>

    ...
</div>;
```

Comment: `onclick={fetchingId(attributes.id)}` - did you forget the `() =>` as in `onclick={() => fetchingId(attributes.id)}` ? Because you should actually *pass a function* and *not the result* of a function call. Otherwise, that would result in the `fetchingId()` being called everytime the component is rendered.. See [this FAQ on the React website](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-functions.html#why-is-my-function-being-called-every-time-the-component-renders), but that "pass a function" is not just in React - even in native JS, that's indeed how it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not supposed to make HTTP requests etc directly inside React components, you need to use `useEffect`.

A react component needs to run as quickly as possible, even if work that needs doing isn't finished yet. By using `useEffect` you tell React to run a separate function after rendering is complete, giving you the opportunity to make requests and for your component to have "effects". React also lets you pass a list of dependencies that it will watch, and if they change the effect re-runs.

What you have however, is a side effect that runs directly in the component. As a result, whenever the component is re-rendered, your code makes a HTTP fetch, which aside from this problem is also going to significantly slow down the editor. A re-render could happen at any time by design. A window resize, stray dom event, state changes in parent components, etc

If it helps, a common way to show this is with something like this:

```js
const { isLoading, setLoading } = useState( false );
```

This way you can call `setLoading( false )` at the end of your `useEffect` function, and then display a loading message in the component

> This is another part of the function: an input that updates the Product ID that is used for the GET request and a button linked to the fetchingId() function.

You cannot rely on those values being present here. You can trigger a function via an event, and that function can have side effects such as HTTP requests, but you can't do those things directly in the component. Rendering the component should render the component, and ***only*** render the component, everything else goes in lifecycle hooks/functions

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation !
I've been trying to use `useEffect` but I cannot find where to put it.
Should it be after the `registerBlockType` function ?
Should I import `useEffect` from `react` ?

Comment: `useEffect` is a react hook, it isn't a WordPress thing, import it like this: `import { useEffect } from '@wordpress/element';` otherwise it works the same way as in any other React component.

Comment: Remember, your edit component is not a block. A block ***has/contains*** an _edit_ component, aka a React component. It's just React, look up any react tutorial on useEffect, useState, or react hooks

Comment: This answer is not good. Does not demonstrate on how to implement

Comment: @user1020989 a copy paste example is not possible here, instead you're best reading the official React docs for `useEffect`, you can't put side effects such as HTTP requests directly into a component